# Difference between usercontrol in datatemplate and in "main" grid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I created user control, whose datacontext is set from another user control. When I insert this usercontrol in main grid, it works fine.

```
<Grid>
    <local:ShowListView DataContext="{Binding ShowListViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

But when I insert it via DataTemplate, like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type showViewModels:ShowListViewModel}">
        <local:ShowListView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Grid>
```

It throws this error

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data.

ShowListView control contains this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Shows}" BorderBrush="Transparent"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

and the relevant viewmodel

```
public ObservableCollection<ShowModel> Shows { get; set; }

public ShowListViewModel()
{
    using (var db = new MSDBContext())
    {
        var shows = (from s in db.Shows select s).ToList();

        Shows = new ObservableCollection<ShowModel>(shows);
    }
}
```

Why the first method works without problem, but second one throws error? What should I change that it works with Datatemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DataContext attribute of the UserControl in the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type showViewModels:ShowListViewModel}">
    <local:ShowListView />
</DataTemplate>
```

The ShowListView will automatically get the ShowListViewModel object as its DataContext when the template is applied providing that you don't explicitly set its DataContext property somewhere.

You should also make sure to execute the query before populating the `ObservableCollection` with the results. You can do this by calling the `ToList()` method:

```
public ShowListViewModel()
{         
    using (var db = new MSDBContext())
    {
        var shows = (from s in db.Shows select s).ToList();

        Shows = new ObservableCollection<Show>(shows);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I removed DataContext (I tried both variants before without success) and added ToList to show variable. And it still throws me the error. `ToObservableCollection` method just takes IEnumerable and changes it to Observable Collection (via contructor with IEnumarable argument).

Comment: What if you simply use the constructor to create a new ObservableCollection instead of using the ToObservableCollection method?

Comment: I had this method because I didnt notice this constructor and the method was with foreach. I tried it directly (as seen in updated mainpost) with same result.

Comment: You will need to provide a full reproducible sample of your issue. Are you sure this doesn't work? Shows = new ObservableCollection<ShowModel>(db.Shows.ToList()); If you uncomment this line do you still get the same exception?

Comment: Even this doesn't work. It works, but only when I insert user control in grid, when I use it ContentControl and DatatTemplate it doesn't. In debug, the shows and Shows content correct datatypes (List or ObservableCollection) and correct data.

Comment: Ok, it works, Im just **** and left some codebehind from previous attempts which I forgot to erase. I changed data context in it and thanks for that it failed. Thanks for your help.